# Problema con URL amigable

Tags: php, .htaccess

Estoy haciendo una página web que al iniciar sesión se muestra el siguiente `url`:

```
marmartex.com/views/producto.php
```

Y estoy tratando de que la URL quede de la siguiente manera:

```
marmartex.com/producto
```

Sinceramente no se nada de `.htaccess` y esto fue lo que implemente y encontre en internet:

```
Options -Indexes

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^producto/$    /views/producto.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes probar con esto .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

# el navegador solicita php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^\ ]+)\.php
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)\.php$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# verifica si su solicitud es para un archivo php:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /$1.php [L]
```

Para mas información puedes ingresar [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29542588/remove-php-from-url) donde ya fue resuelto un inconveniente similar, espero pueda ayudarte.

Comment: en SOes es buena práctica explicar que hace tu código, así la gente que llega con el mismo problema a esa pregunta sabe que hace, y no un "pues lo busqué en internet y funcionó" :D

Comment: Gracias por la sugerencia, mi intensión es poder ayudarlos, sin embargo esta respuesta corresponde a un problema que ya fue solucionado en stackoverflow, por eso adjunte el link por si quieren indagar un poco más.

Comment: Exacto amigo ya fue solucionada allá, pero acá en la versión en español ayudara mucho a futuros lectores el conocer el contenido detallado de tu aporte